# Xerces DOM parser incredibly slow?

Tags: java, performance, dom, xerces

Currently, I am trying to clean up an HTML file using JTidy, convert it to XHTML and provide the results to a DOM parser. The following code is the result of these efforts:

```
public class HeaderBasedNewsProvider implements INewsProvider {

    /* ... */

    public Collection<INewsEntry> getNewsEntries() throws NewsUnavailableException {
            Document document;
        try {
            document = getCleanedDocument();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NewsUnavailableException(e);
        }
        System.err.println(document.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());
        return null;
    }

    private final Document getCleanedDocument() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        InputStream input = inputStreamProvider.getInputStream();
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream tidyOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tidy.parse(input, tidyOutputStream);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        InputStream domInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tidyOutputStream.toByteArray());
        System.err.println(factory.getClass());
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(domInputStream);
    }
}
```

However, the DOM parser implementation (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl) on my system seems to be incredibly slow. Even for one-line documents such as the following, parsing takes 2-3 minutes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head><title></title></head><body><div class="text"><h2>Nachricht vom 16. Juni 2011</h2><h1>Titel</h1><p>Mitteilung <a href="dokumente/medienmitteilungen/MM_NR_jglp.pdf" target="_blank">weiter</a> mehr Mitteilung</p></div></body></html>
```

Note that - in contrast to the DOM parser - JTidy finishes its work within a second. Therefore, I suspect that I'm somehow misusing the DOM API.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on this one!

Comment: Very odd. Shouldn't be anywhere near that slow on such a small document. And since you explicitly set validation to false, I wouldn't expect it to resolve stuff from the DTD. Can you run this through a profiler to find out what calls take the most time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even when not validating, a XML parser needs to fetch the DTD, for example to support named character entities. You should look into implementing an [EntityResolver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html) that resolves the request for the DTD to a local copy.

Comment: This is the issue... I've ran the code through a profiler and 98.9% of the execution time (amounting to 120 seconds) was spent in `java.net.SocketInputStream.read`. This in turn originates from a `HttpURLConnection` which is created by an `XMLDTDScannerImpl` from the JRE's internal Xerces parser. Even with standard DTD validation disabled, it's still gonna need those entity declarations. Never used DTD myself (always locally available schemas). +1

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, I just verified it in my example. As a matter of convenience, Xerces allows disabling DTD fetching using a feature setting:
`factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);`
Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: See http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html for the other available features.

Answer (score 2):

HTML dtd's are huge, using includes. They take forever. Use an [XML catalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog). There one can store the dtds locally and map them by their system ID.

If you use a tool, like maven, you will find sufficient pointers.

The advantage i.o. intercepting entities as the accepted answer suggests, is that you receive the correct characters.