# xerces stalls on getting xhtml1-transitional DTD

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I'd like to perform XPath queries on an XML document online. I've set up InputStreams that retrieve the content and append a `<?xml ...?>` header that declares the encoding present in `charset` field of the HTTP requests. Although it works, it's painfully slow.

```
    //bis is the BufferedInputStream with the content part of the HTTP reply
docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); // throws exception.
Document doc = docBuilder.parse
    (new PrependInputStream(bis,
                "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='"+charset+"' ?>\r\n"));
```

(please allow me not to put my whole source this time: I'm preparing an assignment for students).

Some strace analysis revealed that the program stalls when contacting w3.org:

```
 send(8, "GET /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Java/1.6.0_17\r\nHost: www.w3.org\r\nAccept: 
      text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n", 186, 0)
 recv(8, ...
```

As I don't worry too much about the HTML content to be valid (well-formed should be enough), I tried `docBuilderFactory.setValidating(false)`  but that doesn't seem to prevent online retrieval of the DTD.

<s>Trying to set manually a schema with `docBuilderFactory.setSchema()` using the same dtd file retrieved manually results in a "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.</s>  " (that was not a good idea)

Where am I over-complicating things?

(the XML backend seems to be com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema, as far as I can tell from stack traces -- if that's of any use).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956734/xerces-dom-parser-incredibly-slow has the answer. This question can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Help/Webmaster#slowdtd

Comment: @Sperberg-McQueen: I'm not surprised. That's pretty normal for a consortium s.a. w3 to avoid being overwhelmed by requests issued from code-in-progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML dtd's are huge, using includes. And you are right, they take forever. Use an [XML catalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog). There one can store the dtds locally and map them by their system ID.

If you use a tool, like maven, you will find sufficient pointers.

The advantage i.o. intercepting entities as the answer linked by @sylvainulg suggests, is that you receive the correct characters.